# Нужна помощь с view функциями и html

Tags: python, html, django

я полнейший чайник, делающий учебный проект. Идея такова - сайт для создания учебных тестов. Помогите с view функциями и html для прохождения и создания тестов.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db import models
from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime


class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    timer = models.SmallIntegerField(default=360, blank=True)
    # неположительные значение <=> неограниченные кол-во попыток,
    limit_of_tries = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    # отвечает за показывание правильных ответов теста после прохождения
    visible_valid_answers = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    # для выборки
    tag_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=32)


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Answer(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        ('radio', 'Переключатель.'),
        ('checkbox', 'Флажок.'),
        ('textbox', 'Ввод.'),
    )
    answer_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=TYPES)
    # сколько баллов дается если ответ правильный
    score = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    # текст вар. ответа
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    # правильность ответа
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Вводятся.
    answer_input = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    valid_input = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ResultsPassing(models.Model):
    pupil = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    used_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: и в чем собственно вопрос то?

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите вашу проблему более конкретно. Например, какие части программы вы не знаете как реализовать.

Comment: не понимаю, как написать view функцию для создания Exercise(сам тест) и функцию для множества Question, ну и Answer

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.